# PHP - DOMDocument - need to change/replace an existing HTML tag w/ a new one

Tags: php, html, tags

I need to change an `<img>` tag for a `<video>` tag. I
do not know how to continue with the code as I can change all tags provided they contain a WebM.

```
function iframe($text) {
    $Dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $Dom->loadHTML($text);
    $links = $Dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('src');
        if (!empty($href)) {
            $pathinfo = pathinfo($href);
            if (strtolower($pathinfo['extension']) === 'webm') {
                //If extension webm change tag to <video>
            }        
        }
    }
    $html = $Dom->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Roman i'm using http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php

but i'm using a for-iteration and test for `.webm` extension in the src with a simple strpos().

```
$contents = <<<STR
this is some HTML with an <img src="test1.png"/> in it.
this is some HTML with an <img src="test2.png"/> in it.
this is some HTML with an <img src="test.webm"/> in it,
but it should be a video tag - when iframe() is done.
STR;

function iframe($text)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($text);

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

    for ($i = $images->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
        $nodePre = $images->item($i);
        $src     = $nodePre->getAttribute('src');
        // search in src for ".webm"
        if(strpos($src, '.webm') !== false ) {

            $nodeVideo = $dom->createElement('video');
            $nodeVideo->setAttribute("src", $src);
            $nodeVideo->setAttribute("controls", '');

            $nodePre->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeVideo, $nodePre);
        }
    }

    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
    return $html;
};

echo iframe($contents);
```

Part of output:

```
this is some HTML with an <video src="test.webm"></video> in it,
but it should be a video tag - when iframe() is done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
(...)
if( strtolower( $pathinfo['extension'] ) === 'webm') 
{
    //If extension webm change tag to <video>
    $new = $Dom->createElement( 'video', $link->nodeValue );
    foreach( $link->attributes as $attribute )
    {
        $new->setAttribute( $attribute->name, $attribute->value );
    }
    $link->parentNode->replaceChild( $new, $link );
}
(...)
```

By code above I create a new node with `video` tag and `nodeValue` as `img` node value, then I add to new node all `img` attributes, and finally I replace old node with new node.

Please note that if the old node has `id`, the code will produce a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `DOMDocument::createElement` and `DOMNode::replaceChild` functions:

```
function iframe($text) {
    $Dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $Dom->loadHTML($text);
    $links = $Dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('src');
        if (!empty($href)) {
            $pathinfo = pathinfo($href);
            if (strtolower($pathinfo['extension']) === 'webm') {
                //If extension webm change tag to <video>
                $video = $Dom->createElement('video');
                $video->setAttribute("src", $href);
                $video->setAttribute("controls", '');
                $link->parentNode->replaceChild($video, $link);
            }        
        }
    }
    $html = $Dom->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php

http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php

Comment: In the second agragado tag attribute control does not appear so add a line to work properly

$ video-> setAttribute ("controls", '');